# Right way to stop export operator from saving with empty filename?

Tags: python, scripting, export

If I have a basic save/export operator like this:

```
class SaveData(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.save"
    bl_label = "Save"
    filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype="FILE_PATH")

    def execute(self, context):
        do_save(ensure_ext(self.filepath, ".mytype"))
        return {"FINISHED"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
```

**What is the right/idiomatic way to prevent that that from saving a file named `.mytype` if the user just hits `Save` without supplying a filename?** This bad behavior appears to be common behavior among many Blender plugins (whether they give a Python traceback or save a `.ext` file just depends on whether they happen to call `ensure_ext()` or something similar)

What I have tried:

- The `check` method is not clearly documented, but it appears to be for checking parameters before `invoke`, not after.
- The `execute` method could check for empty `self.filepath` but I've found zero examples of that. This would occur after the file selector has closed, so it would require popping another modal to warn the user that nothing happened.
- The native Save/Save As for `.blend` files aggressively puts `.blend` into the filepath if you try to clear it, so I guess technically you can't save with no filename, but it will happily write a file named `.blend`. There also doesn't seem to be any way to turn on that behavior for other file selectors.
- The `FILE_OT_execute` (which is the operator for the `Save` or `Load` button in the file selector) has a promising property named `need_active` which looks (from reading the C source) like it makes the button do nothing in case no file is selected. But I don't understand how I would set that property because that is used internally by `fileselect_add()`. This behavior would match other Windows programs I've tested.

Answer (score 3):

**ImportHelper and ExportHelper mixin classes.**

If you look at either the import or export operator templates in the text editor will see they use the helper mixin classes `ImportHelper` and `ExportHelper`

Here is the code for export helper from `bpy_extras.io_utils`  find it in the `scripts/modules` folder of your blender installation.

```
class ExportHelper:
    filepath: StringProperty(
        name="File Path",
        description="Filepath used for exporting the file",
        maxlen=1024,
        subtype='FILE_PATH',
    )
    check_existing: BoolProperty(
        name="Check Existing",
        description="Check and warn on overwriting existing files",
        default=True,
        options={'HIDDEN'},
    )

    # subclasses can override with decorator
    # True == use ext, False == no ext, None == do nothing.
    check_extension = True

    def invoke(self, context, _event):
        import os
        if not self.filepath:
            blend_filepath = context.blend_data.filepath
            if not blend_filepath:
                blend_filepath = "untitled"
            else:
                blend_filepath = os.path.splitext(blend_filepath)[0]

            self.filepath = blend_filepath + self.filename_ext

        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def check(self, _context):
        import os
        change_ext = False
        change_axis = _check_axis_conversion(self)

        check_extension = self.check_extension

        if check_extension is not None:
            filepath = self.filepath
            if os.path.basename(filepath):
                filepath = bpy.path.ensure_ext(
                    filepath,
                    self.filename_ext
                    if check_extension
                    else "",
                )

                if filepath != self.filepath:
                    self.filepath = filepath
                    change_ext = True

        return (change_ext or change_axis)
```

which as you can see sets the name to "untitled." if not set.

Check out the templates to see other properties that are used to extend this

```
# ExportHelper mixin class uses this
filename_ext = ".txt"

filter_glob: StringProperty(
    default="*.txt",
    options={'HIDDEN'},
    maxlen=255,
```

Also a files collection [bpy/file browser: get selected file names](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30678/bpy-file-browser-get-selected-file-names) where `directory` is used to designate the folder the files reside in.

[Set custom location for import/export helper](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79373/set-custom-location-for-import-export-helper)