# Addon: how to make Blender run check()/redraw when option changed?

Tags: python, add-on

Operators have a [`check()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=check#bpy.types.Operator.check) function that Blender calls when it wants to check if it should redraw. Exporters usually use this to attach a file extension to the file name ([eg](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/1176591574f9ec5ead51c512dbe77c3cc7972d6d/release/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/io_utils.py#L87)).

I know `check()` already runs after the user has edited the filename field, or after they click a file in the filepicker. I would like it to run after the user changes an option too. For example, the glTF exporter does this:

[image: Filename changes with option]

If the prop is drawn by the `operator.draw()` function this happens automatically. **However it does not happen automatically if the option is drawn by a separate panel. How can I get it to update in that case?**

Here is a complete example you can test with: https://pastebin.com/2k6mBNGz

(PS. I already know how the glTF exporter does it. I'm interested in a "proper" solution.)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the glTF exporter does it?

Comment: @batFINGER The EnumProperty is given an [update function](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/blob/abff7d636f65f6fe34f932e67dc7844ede39dedb/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py#L73-L87) that calls the operator bpy.ops.file.filenum (that's the plus/minus buttons in the file field that add numbers to the end of the filename) in a way designed to have no net change on the filename.

Comment: Oh Ok. Have answered similar in that using an update method, however simply adjusting the spacedata field for file name instead of using the operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Set the filebrowser filename**

The code for the ExportHelper mixin class is shown in this question [Right way to stop export operator from saving with empty filename?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198831/right-way-to-stop-export-operator-from-saving-with-empty-filename/198924#198924)

As demonstrated in question it appears only the `FILE_PT_operator` is live wired to update the parameters using check.

```
def update_ext(self, context):
    # if we wish to set filename_ext
    self.filename_ext = f".{self.extension.lower()}"
    #the filebrowser parameters
    params  = context.space_data.params
    # printed to console
    for k in dir(params):
        print(k, getattr(params, k))
    # set the file name  
    params.filename = f"{Path(self.filepath).stem}.{self.extension.lower()}"
```

And use this as an update on the operator enum

```
extension: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name='Extension',
    items=(('FOO', '.foo', '.foo'), ('BAR', '.bar', '.bar')),
    default='FOO',
    update = update_ext,
)
```

If also using filename_ext make it a property and give it a default to match the enum, however can pretty much do without. The `check_existing` if set will deal with alerting re pre-existing. (Assume it does haven't checked)

So can pretty much replace the check method to redraw the file browser properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is an improvement over the filenum operator :) One addition: context.space_data needs some checks to make sure it's the expected file browser, or else the operator won't work when eg. called from the Python console.

Comment: When I try to do this in my own addon, the console barks at me with this message: "AttributeError: 'EXPORT_OT_gml' object has no attribute 'filename_ext'" - why might this happen? Am I using my update_ext() in the wrong context?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `getter/setter` functions for these kind of updates or can check them in `modal` functions by checking `left clicks`.

an example of `getter/setter` functions is described in API like below:

```
import bpy


# Simple property reading/writing from ID properties.
# This is what the RNA would do internally.
def get_float(self):
    # do some stuff here before get
    return self.get("myfloat",0.0)

# self in this method is the object which you attach the property to
# in this case self is any scene in bpy.data for example bpy.data.scenes[0]
def set_float(self, value):
    # do some stuff here before/after set because no return is required
    self["myfloat"] = value


bpy.types.Scene.myfloat = bpy.props.FloatProperty(get=get_float, set=set_float)
```

now whenever you get/set a `scene.myfloat` data above methods work.

Comment: Recommend you test this. Returning the "got" value from the getter will recurse. Use the ID prop to emulate what the `rna` does.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134310/15543

Comment: Thanks @batFinger. You are true with this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Can you please phrase the answer as a diff on the pastebin in the question that will make it work?