# Import multiple STL files and modify the incoming objects in one go?

Tags: python, import, operator, stl

I want to import stl files using file browser (by using `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` on import stl operator). It seems that `join()` operator gets called before importing is finished. Does Blender import the objects in some kind of seperate thread to prevent a potential freeze?

I also tried macros but I'm getting the same result. `join()` operator gets called before the import is finished. I came across this method of window manager [`window_manager.fileselect_add()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=fileselect_add#bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add) but couldn't get it to work. Sure, I can import the objects if that's finished, the user can join them but the client requires these two steps to be done using one single button.

```
import bpy


def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        return context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Q:** Is there any way I can import and join the objects in one go?

Comment: Umm... can you just exactly tell what you want to achieve here. It is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Aster17 I want a operator that imports stl files and join all imported models.

Comment: This appears to be  little more than  pasting the simple operator template.  Would say comment re joining finishing before import is akin to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212179/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-the-open-file-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [Import STL via python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201782/import-stl-via-python/201796#201796), you can use the [`ImportHelper`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.io_utils.html?highlight=importhelper#bpy_extras.io_utils.ImportHelper) class if you'd like to **import** and **modify** objects. Have a look into the *Operator File Import* template that comes with Blender.

In order to join the objects, see [@batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger)s answer on: [How to join objects with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13986/how-to-join-objects-with-python) How to import multiple objects using the file browser, you can find here: [How to batch import Wavefront OBJ files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31825/31447)

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
# <pep8 compliant>


bl_info = {
    "name": "Custom Batch Import Stl (.stl)",
    "author": "brockmann",
    "version": (0, 1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "File > Import-Export",
    "description": "Import Stl files and join them",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Import-Export"}


import bpy
import os

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import StringProperty, CollectionProperty


class ImportSomeData(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    """Batch Import Stl files and join them"""
    bl_idname = "import_scene.custom_stls"
    bl_label = "Import multiple OBJ's"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}

    # ImportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".stl"

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
            default="*.stl",
            options={'HIDDEN'},
            )

    # Selected files
    files: CollectionProperty(type=PropertyGroup)

    def execute(self, context):

        # Get the folder
        folder = os.path.dirname(self.filepath)
        
        obs = []
        # Iterate through the selected files
        for i in self.files:

            # Generate full path to file
            path_to_file = (os.path.join(folder, i.name))
            bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=path_to_file)
            # Append Object(s) to the list
            obs.append(context.selected_objects[:])
            # Print the imported object reference
            print ("Imported object:", context.object)
        
        # Join the objects based on: 
        # https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133024/
        obs = [x for sublist in obs for x in sublist]
        c = {}
        c["object"] = c["active_object"] = context.object
        c["selected_objects"] = c["selected_editable_objects"] = obs
        bpy.ops.object.join(c)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ImportSomeData.bl_idname, text="Stl Batch & Join (.stl)")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ImportSomeData)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ImportSomeData)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.remove(menu_func_import)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.import_scene.custom_stls('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

**Note:** If you get paid for that and my code got your job done, please consider making a donation here: https://www.blender.org/foundation/donation-payment/ to make up for that.

Comment: _Very altruistic of you_  Mr Brockman.   May be interested in Updated version of multi file import helper https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30678/bpy-file-browser-get-selected-file-names/198926#198926  `obs.extend(sublist)` ?`

Comment: I guess this won't happen anyway @batFINGER Nice, thanks for the link! I'll leave up any improvement to the OP...

Comment: @brockmann That is just magic. Script works like charms. And As soon as i get paid i'll definitely make a donation.

Comment: Cool, keep us posted @PavanBhadaja