# Can I prevent user from importing a non-existant or incorrect file in an import operator?

Tags: python, import, operator

Losing my Blender flower on this one :)

I'm using an operator to select the filepath of a .txt file.

```
import bpy

class SelectTxtFile(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "file.select_txt"
    bl_label = "Select TXT File"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype="FILE_PATH")
    filter_glob: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="*.txt", options={"HIDDEN"})

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.filepath)
        return {"FINISHED"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectTxtFile)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.file.select_txt('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

[image]

I don't want the user to be able to validate the operator (Blue button) if the file they selected isn't a valid .txt file.

I want the button to be clickable only when :

- The user selected a file and it exists : [os.path.isfile(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) returns `True`
- The extension is .txt : [os.path.splitext(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) returns `".txt"`

I would like to insert this line somewhere :

```
layout.enabled = os.path.isfile(self.filepath) and os.path.splitext(self.filepath)[1] == ".txt"
```

I'd like it to be grayed out if the conditions are not met. But I can't access this particular layout button because it's apparently managed by the window manager.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Looks promising https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.file.html#bpy.ops.file.execute  re the `need_active` parameter   Maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207665/15543

Comment: @batFINGER That looks exactly like what I'm looking for and I learned a lot from your answer and related threads, but I still can't seem to access that particular operator to change this parameter... I'll keep looking :) I'm starting to wonder if I can just remove this bottom strip with the filename, operator and cancel button and redraw it myself.

Comment: dig into `wm.fileselect_add` which AFAIK invokes  the filebrowser to run modally and  appends  the footer. Highly  recommend  `pathlib` over `os.path` _shenanigans_