# Get name of the ExportHelper text field

Tags: python, export

When I use the following script:

```
import bpy
import os
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import (StringProperty, CollectionProperty)
from bpy.types import (Operator, OperatorFileListElement,)


class OT_ExportTest(Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_label = 'Export'
    bl_idname = 'test.export_test'
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO', 'REGISTER'}
    files: CollectionProperty(name = 'File Path',
                              type = OperatorFileListElement,)
    directory: StringProperty(subtype = 'DIR_PATH',)
    filter_glob: StringProperty(default = "*.fbx;", options={'HIDDEN'})
    filename_ext = ''

    def execute(self, context):
        folder_path = os.path.dirname(self.filepath)
        selection = bpy.context.selected_objects
        for sel in selection:
            filename_ext = '.fbx'
            bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(
                    filepath = folder_path + os.sep + sel.name + filename_ext)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OT_ExportTest)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OT_ExportTest)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
    bpy.ops.test.export_test('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

The object always get exported as the name of the object, because of `sel.name`.

But I want the object to be exported as what you type into the text field.
How do I do that?
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207665/15543

Comment: I got it by using this self.filepath.split('\\')[-1]

Comment: which  will only work on MS Windows OS.

Comment: How would it work on different OS'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579908/cross-platform-splitting-of-path-in-python