# Addon: how to update filename on EnumProperty change?

Tags: python, export, add-on, file-browser

I'm working on a Blender (2.93) addon that outputs models to a few different formats. There is an EnumProperty in the filebrowser which lets the user choose which format to output to. The formats are different enough that I feel they should each have their own filename extension, but I cannot figure out how to do this properly.

This is the code I'm using for exports, with some of the irrelevant properties trimmed out:

```
class ExportData(Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_idname = "export.gtd"
    bl_label = "Export"
    
    filename_ext = ".buf"
    
    def update_ext(self, context):
        new_ext = ".buf"
        if self.output_type == 'vertex_buffer':
            new_ext = "buf"
        else:
            new_ext = "gml"
        params = context.space_data.params
        context.space_data.params.filename = f"{Path(self.filepath).stem}.{new_ext}"
    
    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="*.buf;*.gtd",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255,
    )

    output_type: EnumProperty(
        name = "Output Type",
        description="The type of data to output",
        items = (
            ('vertex_buffer', "Vertex Buffer", "A vertex buffer that can be loaded at runtime"),
            ('debug', "GTD Script (debug)", "A human-readable script that can be used to import and debug"),
        ),
        default = 'vertex_buffer',
        update = update_ext,
    )
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return export_gtd(context, self.filepath, self.output_type)
```

When I run this code, I can use the console to verify that the `filename_ext` changes, and it will print the correct filename if I print `context.space_data.params.filename`. There are two problems, however:

- The `filename_ext` variable always forces a single filename extension on the output, and I can't figure out how to change it.
- The actual filename at the bottom of the filebrowser doesn't update when I change the choice in the EnumProperty.

I've been studying this answer: [Addon: how to make Blender run check()/redraw when option changed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203747/addon-how-to-make-blender-run-check-redraw-when-option-changed), but the suggestions/solutions there don't seem to work. Would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction on this!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203747/addon-how-to-make-blender-run-check-redraw-when-option-changed  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198831/right-way-to-stop-export-operator-from-saving-with-empty-filename/198924#198924

Comment: The code I ended up with is [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/blob/0ccb1ae99da9382c96a3562d22e82828f2cbc45c/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py#L94-L108). Most obvious difference is the update function is a free function, not a member function like you have.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - still a little unclear on what makes the filename update, however. @scurest - Just to test, I can drop in the two functions you've written, `on_export_format_changed` and `ensure_filepath_matches_export_format`, and I can print out what's returned at the end to see that the correct filename is produced.

The filename in the window does not update, though - and any attempt to change the extension by typing a new one in is just reset every time the filename box loses focus.

Is there some aspect of the filebrowser window that needs to be overridden?

Comment: Oops - I just noticed in the link that @batFINGER shared that you added the `check()` to your export class, and now that seems to be working correctly for me.

I think that might be the solution I was missing. Thank you both for your help!