# Python export to specific path

Tags: python

I want to export a list with all my objects in my scene, but it always outputs to the default folder.
I already have a little UI and when I press the button it should open the file browser and I want to set the specific path. [image]

Is there a way to it?

Here is the operator it should work in

```
 #Operator Export
    class RGL_OT_export(bpy.types.Operator):
        bl_idname = "object.export"
        bl_label = "Regalplannung"
        bl_description = "Exportier Bestückung"
        
        
        def execute(self, context):     
                    
            selection = bpy.context.selected_objects
            result = ""
                        
            for sel in selection:
    
                bpy.context.object.modifiers["Vollständig gefüllt"].show_viewport = False
    
                parent = sel.parent
                parent_0 = parent.dimensions [0]
                parent_1 = parent.dimensions [1]
                parent_2 = parent.dimensions [2]
                
                x = (sel.name.split("_")[0])
                y = (sel.name.split("_")[1])
                z = (sel.name.split("_")[2])
                h = (sel.name.split("_")[3])
                
                if parent_0 < parent_1:
                    dims = parent.dimensions [0] / sel.dimensions [0]
                else:
                    dims = parent.dimensions [1] / sel.dimensions [1]
        
            result += "%s - %s - %s - %s - %f\n" % (x, y, z, h, dims)
    
            tempFolder = os.path.abspath (bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)
            filename = os.path.join (tempFolder, "newfile.txt")
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
            file = open(filename, "w")
            file.write(result)
            file.close()
            return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Hello, could you post a snippet of your current code so we can start from it ?

Comment: @Gorgious I edited my question and added the code :)

Comment: could not find an exact duplicate but basically you need to modify your operator to inherit from `ExportHelper` and use an `invoke` method. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30678/bpy-file-browser-get-selected-file-names https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198831/right-way-to-stop-export-operator-from-saving-with-empty-filename/198924 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79373/set-custom-location-for-import-export-helper

Comment: You should find a pretty solid example in the text editor by going Templates > Python > Operator file export

Comment: BTW when you have a context passed as parameter in a method, you should use that one instead of `bpy.context`

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick help, definitely gonna check out the links and the template.